# How to keep a columns formula applied to a newly added row?

Tags: worksheet-function, google-spreadsheets

I have a recurring formula down an entire column but every time I add a row the formula isn't applied to those new cells in that column.  How can I make the formula permanent so it is consistently applied to all cells in that column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In Excel: Convert your data to a table:

**Insert tab - Table**

This way the formulas will be automatically inserted in new rows (you may need to edit formula entered before conversion to table, to let Excel know that it's the formula to be used in the column (just press <kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>))

Answer (score 0):

Rather than selecting a row and choosing to Insert rows
Select the row.
 COPY ... then
  Insert copied cells